# Passing response to upstream proxy only in certain cases

Tags: mitmproxy

I am trying to implement routing in this manner:

```
                                                                    no
client --> mitmproxy --> (check if hostname is in list of accepted) --> upstream proxy response
                                           |
                                           |  yes
                                           |
                        intercept response, check, return to client
                            + don't allow to propagate upstream
```

I'm trying to implement a dynamic filter which will override the upstream proxy in some cases, and not in other cases.

I have a workaround method which is to have two mitm proxies, one which filters requests and chooses which proxy to use (upstream proxy *or* filter proxy) and then the filter proxy which inspects the content.